# AlertDialog only showing one of two buttons

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I want to display an alert with two buttons: "Reprendre" and "Plus Tard". I have the below code:

```
alertsyncincomplete = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertsyncincomplete.setCustomTitle(titleAlertSyncIncomplete);
alertsyncincomplete.setPositiveButton("Reprendre", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});

alertsyncincomplete.setNegativeButton("Plus tard", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
```

But I am able to only see one of the buttons on the screen — the first one with text "Reprendre". I used `AlertDialog` with `setButton` and `setButton2` methods and I got same result. I changed the text "Plus Tard" to "OK" (which is shorter in length), then both buttons were displayed. I think problem should be with length of the text (even if the text from my buttons is not very long).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YouActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("title");
builder.setMessage("message");
builder.setPositiveButton("Reprendere", null);
builder.setNegativeButton("Plus Tard", null);
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
AlertDialog anAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).create();
                    anAlertDialog.setTitle("");
                    anAlertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout!");
                    anAlertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    anAlertDialog.setButton2("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    anAlertDialog.show();
```